# How can I pass `StatusCallbackEvent` while the number voice is configured with `Application`?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, twilio-twiml

I have configured my number's voice with `Application`. `TWILIO APPS` configuration page don't have the option for `StatusCallbackEvent`. How do I set the `StatusCallbackEvent`for other events beside the default one?

I found an alternative . [passing parameters to the `<client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can set the Status Callback URL on a TwiML application by opening the Optional Settings pane:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was talking about `StatusCallbackEvent`.

Comment: OK, then I guess I'm not clear on what you are asking.  You don't configure StatusCallbackEvents on a TwiML App.  For inbound calls, you use the statusCallbackEvent attribute on the <Client>, <Number> or <Sip> nouns.  For outbound PSTN calls made using the REST API you pass the statusCallbackEvents parameter with your post request.  Are you asking how you use statusCallbackEvents when making a call from an instance of Twilio Client?

Comment: I am using attributes on client but I thought there might be an option to set statuscallbackevents that I missed in Twilio Apps configuration page. I guess what I had done is the correct way.